# How to make an item in a flexbox container to expand on hover to 2 columns without moving/affecting the remaining items?

Tags: flexbox, hover, webflow

I'm trying to recreate this interaction on Webflow.
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6BZh.gif)

So far, I have been successful in recreating [this](https://symmetric-consultancy-3f6eeb.webflow.io/all-trainings/microsoft)

Everything works fine, except that the third column item on each row moves down to the next row on hover which ends up creating this blinking effect
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKVpI.gif)

How can I prevent this blinking from happening and instead just have the item in the 3rd column expand on hover on the same row?

Answer (score 0):

from as much i understand from your statement, first i found that after hovering on card it's not growing smoothly so you need to apply interaction on that so hover effect will look soomth. then add overflow on the row after hovering on 3rd card i will not expand over the right hand section (after hovering on 3rd card make first card hide)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).